# Gamma Convergence of functionals on Probability measures

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, calculus-of-variations

Would be grateful if someone could provide a hint or an appropriate reference for the following.

Notation:

$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$- Space of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$

$g_n\stackrel{\Gamma}{\longrightarrow}g$ denotes gamma convergence of appropriate space

Question

Let $(\rho_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and  $f_n:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a sequence of functions. Define, $F_n(\rho):=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}f_n(x)\rho(dx)$.

Prove that: $f_n\stackrel{\Gamma}{\longrightarrow}f$ in $\mathbb{R}^n \Longleftrightarrow F_n\stackrel{\Gamma}{\longrightarrow}F$ in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Remarks: 
(1) I am looking to use narrow convergence of probability measures ($\rho_n$) in context of proving $\Gamma$ convergence of $F_n$.
(2) This usually pops up in existence of solution to some Fokker-Planck type of equation. More specifically it pops in Sandier-Serfaty framework for Gradient flows.

Comment: Do you mean the Gamma convergence like in the link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%93-convergence

Comment: Yeah that's the one. Apologies for not providing the definition in the question itself.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this/ reference?

Comment: Where does it pop up in the sandier-serfaty paper? I didn't see any mention of narrow convergence in that paper.

Comment: @900edges To be honest this question was so long ago that I don't remember the context anymore, sorry. My guess is that I was trying to apply Sandier-Serfaty idea to a specific variational structure (gradient flow structure coming from large deviations proposed by Peletier and co-authors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the answer, but here are some ideas.

To show that $f_n \stackrel{\Gamma}{\rightarrow} f$ implies $F_n \stackrel{\Gamma}{\rightarrow} F$, you could do the following:
\begin{align*}
\liminf F_n(\rho_n) &= \liminf \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_n(x) \rho_n(dx) 
\\
&\geq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\liminf f_n(x) \rho_n(dx) \quad \text{ by Fatou's lemma}
\\
&\overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_n(x) \rho(dx) \quad \text{ by narrow convergence of $\rho_n$ to $\rho$}
\\
&\geq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \rho(dx) \quad \text{ by } f_n \stackrel{\Gamma}{\rightarrow} f
\\
&= F(\rho)  \,.
\end{align*}

I'm not sure how the third line affects things. If your underlying space was a bounded set, then you could just integrate both sides of the narrow convergence by $1 \in L^1$ and you'd have the result.

The limsup inequality would be similar, knowing that there exists a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ from the Gamma-convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ for which the fourth line follows.